# Trying to ask n-of 10 turtles to do a random procedure out of a list of three

Tags: netlogo

This is currently what I am struggling with. I am new to netlogo so any help is nice. This is a modification on the 'virus' tutorial.

```
ask n-of 10 turtles[ run (
          ifelse-value 
          choice = 0 [ go-quarantine ] 
          choice = 1 [ wear-mask     ] 
                     [ get-sick      ] ) ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brandon, and welcome!  Yeah the documentation is a little fuzzy on this.

- I think you want just "ifelse", to branch to some action,  not  "ifelse-value" which returns a value.
- you need a "(" before "ifelse" or it won't work. You have the closing ")".
- you do not need a closing "]"
- "choice" is not a necessary magic word.  You can use any logical test.

So the command you're looking for would be this pattern, where white space is flexible in NetLogo and "..." means zero or more things may go there.  I'm old-school and prefer to put parentheses around conditional tests but you don't need to.

```
    (ifelse 
            ( test-1 ) [ actions 1 ...]
            ( test-2 ) [ actions 2 ...]
              ...
            ( test-n ) [ actions n ...]
               ;; else
                       [ default actions ]
    )
```

So say this person has 33.3% chance of going each of those ways.
you could code an instance of this pattern as follows:

```
    let mood random 3  ;; returns integer values of 0, 1, or 2
    ( ifelse
              ( mood = 0 ) [ go-quarantine]
              ( mood = 1 ) [ wear-mask ]
                           [ get-sick ] 
    )
```

where implicitly that code would expect those actions to be defined later:

```
  to go-quarantine [   do this ] end
  to wear-mask [  do that] end
  to get-sick  [  do other stuff ] end
```

And the choices of values of 0, 1, 2 etc. and having them in that order is not required.